# Archos 10i internet tablet SD Card Folder

Tags: sd-card, archos, android

We have developed one application in Android for the Archos 7 home tablet.  With the Archos 7, there is an sdcard folder available.  In code I can get the sdcard location using:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

But with the Archos 10i internet tablet, there is no sdcard folder available. Is there any related folder for sdcard is available in the Archos 10i internet tablet?

Can anybody help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Archos 10.1 had a /mnt/storage folder, that is symlinked from /mnt/storage and /mnt/sdcard. The 'real' sdcard is mounted as /mnt/storage/sdcard. So from the perspective of the app it should behave normally.